Appeal Against Sentence on Grounds of Bias
In England and Wales, can someone appeal their sentence on the ground that the sentencing judge was biased against them? Can someone appeal on this ground even though the sentence was appropriate (i.e. it is one a non-biased judge could have given the defendnant and had upheld on appeal)?
Let’s use the case below as an example:

HZL, a circuit judge, has made extremely Islamophobic, non-public comments a few days before the trial of APJ, a devout Muslim, for an indictable-only offence.
APJ pleads guilty, and HZL is assigned to his sentencing hearing.
Only after his sentence, but long before the appeal deadline, do APJ’s lawyers discover these remarks by HZL.
APJ's lawyers decide to appeal the sentence, on the ground that HZL was not fit to pass it as someone biased against Islam. They believe the sentence should have been given by a non-biased judge.

APJ’s lawyers believe that a second chance at sentencing, by a non-biased judge, may result in a lower sentence, within the accetptable range, for the conducted APJ admitted to. Can they appeal to have APJ re-sentenced, even if HZL gave a sentence within the acceptable range for APJ’s conduct? If APJ’s lawyers could not ordinarily appeal the sentence on this ground, would it be any different if a Netwon hearing had taken place?
For any answer, I would be grateful if any previous cases were cited in support of it.
Thanks for asking. I apologise if any of this is not clear.

canada
Yes, reasonable apprehension of bias is a ground for appeal. The test is:

[T]he apprehension of bias must be a reasonable one, held by reasonable and right minded persons, applying themselves to the question and obtaining thereon the required information. … [T]he test is “what would an informed person, viewing the matter realistically and practically – and having thought the matter through – conclude.

As one example that resulted in a successful appeal on the ground of reasonable apprehension of bias, see R. v. Cowan, 2022 ONCA 432:

The appellant’s trial related to the most serious offence in the Criminal Code – murder. The trial had lasted three weeks. The trial was not over – the trial judge and counsel had just fixed a date for the sentence component of the trial. Within minutes of the jury’s verdict, the trial judge called Crown counsel to suggest they meet for a drink. She did not invite anyone else. The trial judge then agreed to join the Crown, a Crown articling student and a senior police officer involved in the trial at a nearby restaurant. Defence counsel was not invited or present.
Once together inside the restaurant, the trial judge referred to the absence of defence counsel at least twice, whether jokingly or not. The trial was discussed, albeit briefly. After the drinks meeting broke up, the Crown called the trial judge and invited her to dinner. The trial judge accepted and they went to a different restaurant. The four-person drinks meeting, in a public setting, lasted about an hour. The two-person dinner, in a public setting, lasted about two hours.


Interesting. Thanks for this example. I wonder if England and Wales, or any other jurisdiciton in the UK, follows this approach. I would assume it does, but I have struggled to find a case to support this.

For E&W see Magill v Porter [2001] UKHL 67 at 103, "The question is whether the fair-minded and informed observer, having considered the facts, would conclude that there was a real possibility that the tribunal was biased." This is intended to coincide with the test in Canada and elsewhere, outlined in the answer above.

@alexg Has this test ever been used successfully, or acknowledged that it could be used successfully, in an appeal against sentence?

@BakedAlaska624 Not often successfully, but there are many appellate cases where it was alleged that the first-instance judge was biased but the higher court disagreed. For example R v Jordan [2024] EWCA Crim 229, R v Roberts [2018] EWCA Crim 2739 are a couple of recent protest-related cases where convictions were challenged in this way. The Court of Appeal did not consider the arguments legally unsound, just said that the facts were not on the appellants' side.
